# Save a dying rose plant

Tags: flowers, containers, roses, wilt, rot

[image]

Good day everyone!

I would like to ask for some help on how to save my dying rose plant. This rose plant was thought to be dead last year when it dropped all its leaves and I did not remove the "dead" stem from the pot, and just left it unattended. Surprisingly just 5 months ago it sprung back to life when it produced new leaves from its bare stem and after that I have resumed to water it regularly. Now it is happening all over again. Just a week after it produced a flower, some of the leaves suddenly turned yellow, and dropped. And today I noticed that all of its leaves have curled/wilted, and its stem near the base turned brown/black(root rot?).

Is there a way to save this plant? or is it a goner? What could I have done wrong with this ?

I am suspecting that I have over watered it, but I am not really sure. It does get direct sunlight in the morning for about 5 hours (until it gets covered by the shadow cast by the tree behind it). The soil is kind of sandy, so it should drain well. I've only sprayed foliar fertilizer on it thrice in a span of 2 months, and sprinkled a pinch of epsom salt once around the base of the plant. It does not get sprayed with any sort of fungicide or insecticide though (the leaves does not seem to show any infestation).

I would really appreciate any response to this

Comment: You should note that using epsom salts as a soil amendment does nothing positive to the soil - the thought that it helps with magnesium uptake in adequately fertilized soil is a myth (not surprising, the epsom salts makers helped create that myth). See here for more info: https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/epsom-salts.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is the pot - roses don't really do well growing in pots for any length of time. They like to put down quite long woody roots, and that's obviously not possible contained in such a manner.

If you can find somewhere in the garden for it, transplant it now or next month, depending on how cold it is wherever you are (assuming you're in the northern hemisphere). Dig over the area you want to plant it in, preferably working in some composted manure as you go, then transfer the rose into a hole in the middle of the area you've dug over, and water in well.

Fertilizing ongoing is best done with a specialist rose food such as Toprose or similar - this is applied to the soil and raked in around the base of the plant twice, usually in March/April and again about 6-8 weeks later.